# Format a double value like currency but without the currency sign (C#)

Tags: c#, string, format, currency

I feed a textbox a string value showing me a balance that need to be formatted like this:

```
###,###,###,##0.00
```

I could use the value.ToString("c"), but this would put the currency sign in front of it.

Any idea how I would manipulate the string before feeding the textbox to achieve the above formatting?

I tried this, without success:

```
String.Format("###,###,###,##0.00", currentBalance);
```

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
string forDisplay = currentBalance.ToString("N2");
```

Comment: This isn't acceptable because if the negative symbol for currency in the culture is () and the negative symbol for decimals is -, the currency representation will be incorrect.

Comment: @Bob: This is the accepted answer so it is, by definition, acceptable to the OP. Since there's no built-in format specifier for "format like a currency but without the currency symbol" some sort of manual processing would be required in that situation: either *(1)* use a custom `NumberFormatInfo` as per Jon's answer, *(2)* use a custom format string, or *(3)* call `ToString("c")` and then post-process to remove the symbol.

Comment: @LukeH: Although this is the accepted answer the answer that Jon Skeet gives is more correct in the sense that it uses the Currency formattings provided by NumberFormatInfo.

Comment: @D. Patrick: Why? I also find it frustrating when an accepted answer is out-and-out wrong or misleading, but in this case I'm correctly answering the question asked, and presumably that's why the OP chose this as their accepted answer. (Admittedly there's a discrepancy between the question title and what's asked in the question body, but if that's a problem for you then perhaps you could raise the issue with the OP.)

Comment: @LukeH, Bob raised a great point and I don't feel like the question body was "how do you format a number with 2 decimal points and commas."  I thought you brushed off his concern.

But, that's only part of the reason.  "This is the accepted answer, so by definition, it is acceptable to the OP" seems snarky and I don't feel it adds much for the community.  In fact, the OP may well have not accepted your answer had s/he known about the shortcomings and Bob, IMO, was merely trying to point that out.

Comment: Agreed @D.Patrick - I've attempted to address this with my answer below to retain the parentheses for en-US specific culture display.  Jon's solution still handles culture formatting most appropriately if that is a concern.

Answer (score 72):

If the currency formatting gives you exactly what you want, clone a `NumberFormatInfo` with and set the `CurrencySymbol` property to "". You should check that it handles negative numbers in the way that you want as well, of course.

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        NumberFormatInfo nfi = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;
        nfi = (NumberFormatInfo) nfi.Clone();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(nfi, "{0:c}", 123.45m));
        nfi.CurrencySymbol = "";
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(nfi, "{0:c}", 123.45m));
    }
}
```

The other option is to use a custom numeric format string of course - it depends whether you really want to mirror exactly how a currency would look, just without the symbol, or control the exact positioning of digits.

Comment: This works perfectly.  If you want currency to be formatted as the current culture but without the symbol, this seems to be the best solution.

Comment: You might consider adding a Trim() to the result to make sure you have no leading (or trailing) spaces.

Comment: @BenjaminWegman: I'd assume that if the culture-sensitive currency format included whitespace, it's there for some good reason.

Comment: I don't think this technique of setting CurrencySymbol = "" is quite right.  If CurrencyNegativePattern is 8, 11, 12, 13, 14 or 15 then the output has an extra space in it.  I think this is the idea that @BenjaminWegman had about trimming spaces, but for example CurrencyNegativePattern 14 with CurrencySymbol == "$" will give "($ 1,234.56) while CurrencySymbol == "" will give "( 1,234.56)" when "(1,234.56)" is likely desired instead.

Answer (score 11):

Have you tried:

```
currentBalance.ToString("#,##0.00");
```

This is the long-hand equivalent of:

```
currentBalance.ToString("N2");
```

Answer (score 5):

string result=string.Format("{0:N2}", value);   //For result like ### ### ##.##

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with [the group separator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#SpecifierTh) and [the section separator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#SectionSeparator), like this:

```
currentBalance.ToString("#,0.00;(#,0.00)");
```

This does not account for culture variances like the answer from @JonSkeet would, but this does mimic decimal place, rounding, thousands separation, and negative number handling that en-US culture currency format produces using a single custom format string.

[.NET Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lZG27x)

Answer (score 4):

```
var result = currentBalance.ToString("C").Replace(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol, "");
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, you should [edit] your answer to include a brief explanation of *how* this line of code answers the question. This helps to provide context and makes your answer much more useful to those who come across the same issue later on.

Comment: I would also add .Trim() at the end, to remove unwanted spaces.
```var result = currentBalance.ToString("C").Replace(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol, "").Trim();```

Answer (score 2):

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "Rs.";

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
decimal devimalValue = 3.45M;
this.Text = devimalValue.ToString("C2"); //Rs.3.45
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be overkill, but it rounds, formats...

```
@helper TwoDecimalPlaces(decimal? val)
{
    decimal x = 0;
    decimal y = 0;
    string clas = "text-danger";
    if (val.HasValue)
    {
        x = (decimal)val;
        if (val > 0)
        {
            clas = "";
        }
    }
    y = System.Math.Round(x, 2);
    IFormatProvider formatProvider = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(string.Empty);
    <span class="@clas">@string.Format("{0:N2}", y)</span>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple solution works for me with US currency.

If not needing international currency support use this and replace the $ with the currency symbol(s) to be removed:

```
// for USD
string result = currentBalance.ToString("C").Replace("$", "")
```

or

```
// for EUR
string result = currentBalance.ToString("C").Replace("€", "")
```