# How to remove $ symbol from a string

Tags: vb.net, string-function

I am trying to format currency without the "$" in the beginning of the currency format.

How would I do this?  I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
Format(e.Row.Cells(7).Text, "{0:n}")
```

I know that $1,234 is:

```
Format(e.Row.Cells(7).Text, "Currency")
```

But I am trying to remove the

> $

in front of the currency.

Comment: If you don't want currency, do not use currency format. Use a numeric format.

Comment: There's a setting in VS that changed the currency symbol depending on what you want to appear. If you want nothing at all, then use `Integer` or `Decimal/Double`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format a double value like currency but without the currency sign (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048643/format-a-double-value-like-currency-but-without-the-currency-sign-c) http://stackoverflow.com/a/1048669/1316573

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim value As Double = e.Row.Cells(7).Text 
Dim val2 As String
val2 = (value.ToString("#,#", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
e.Row.Cells(7).Text = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:#,#}", val2)
```

> Do not forget the `Imports System.Globalization`

Answer (score 0):

`TrimStart()` function

```
Dim strVal As String = "$1,234"
strVal = strVal.TrimStart("$")
```

`replace()` function

```
Dim strVal As String = "$1,234"
strVal = strVal.Replace("$",String.Empty)
```

you can use like this

```
e.Row.Cells(7).Text = e.Row.Cells(7).Text.TrimStart("$")
```

or

```
e.Row.Cells(7).Text = e.Row.Cells(7).Text.Replace("$",String.Empty)
```