# How to get Current culture formatted number currency

Tags: c#, globalization, cultureinfo, currency-formatting

Using below way, able to get 2 digit currency for current culture. 
`string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:C2}", amount)`
getting the result as: `$1,000.00`

How can we get currency using currency symbol like USD or EUR as below,

expected result: `1,000.00 USD`

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using the `RegionInfo` class:

```
decimal amount = 1000m;

CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
RegionInfo region = RegionInfo.CurrentRegion; //or new RegionInfo(...)
string formattedCurrency = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:C2} {1}", amount, region.ISOCurrencySymbol);
```

In the above code, `formattedCurrency` results in a string value of `"$1,000.00 USD"`.

If you're expecting no currency symbol, you could either do something like `Replace(culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol, "")` or use the `N` specifier instead of `C`. Both result in a value of `"1,000.00 USD"` (with my region/culture). 
This specific topic is addressed in this question: [Format a double value like currency but without the currency sign (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048643/format-a-double-value-like-currency-but-without-the-currency-sign-c/3976048)
Note that the accepted answer (using `N`) appears to not be friendly across all cultures.

Comment: Would there be a reason to replace over using N? Or vice versa?

Comment: Sure @CodeStranger. See first comment on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1048672/2957232. I don't have much experience with other culture's representations, so it appears that Replacing would be preferred here. Another answer blanks the CurrencySymbol on a cloned `NumberFormatInfo`. There are a couple ways to skin this cat.